# Iterate until a condition is met

Tags: php, mysql, loops, iteration, do-while

I am working on a scheduling system and i need your help. I have code running well,

`$t_slot_time` is the current timeslot, if condition is yes on line19, `$t_slot_time` increment by 2, and `$t_slot_times` becomes new time.

how can i repeat same process from 1 to 21 for the new timeslot `$t_slot_times` where `$t_slot_time` on line1 is replaced with the new `$t_slot_times` on line20 and subsequent values after increment until this `$num_rowe >= 1` is not satisfied.

Thanks

```
$queuen = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM put_exam WHERE sess_id ='".$t_slot_time."'") or die(mysql_error());
$arrDatasa = array();
while($rowsa = mysql_fetch_array($queuen))
{
    $arrDatasa[]=$rowsa['course_code']. '|';
    $docam = array_filter($arrDatasa);
}

foreach($arrDatasa as $a=> $rowsa)
{
    $docama .= $docam[$a];
}

//Store current coursecode to assisgn into currentass
$currentass = $e_course_code;

//Check for common student between the last assigned course and current course to be assigned, if yes increment timeslot by 2
$chkcomms = mysql_query("SELECT student.matric, student.std_name FROM student
    JOIN course_reg e1 ON e1.matric=student.matric
    JOIN course c1 ON c1.course_code=e1.course_code
    JOIN course_reg e2 ON e2.matric=student.matric
    JOIN course c2 on c2.course_code = e2.course_code
    WHERE c1.course_code = '".$currentass."'
    AND c2.course_code RLIKE '%$docama%'
    GROUP BY student.matric") or die(mysql_error());

// Count number of rows
$num_rowe = mysql_num_rows($chkcomms);
if($num_rowe >= 1) {
    $t_slot_times = $t_slot_time + 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$num_rowe = mysql_num_rows($chkcomms);
for( $i=0; $i<=$num_rowe; $i++){
    ...
}
```

Is how I usually handle this type of thing!

EDIT: Hopefully I have understood what you are trying to do, also note I have not tested this for errors!

```
function get_codes( $t_slot_time ){
    $queuen = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM put_exam WHERE sess_id ='".$t_slot_time."'") or die(mysql_error());
    $arrDatasa = array();
    while($rowsa = mysql_fetch_array($queuen))
    {
        $arrDatasa[]=$rowsa['course_code']. '|';
        $docam = array_filter($arrDatasa);
    }

    foreach($arrDatasa as $a=> $rowsa)
    {
        $docama .= $docam[$a];
    }

    return $docama;
}

//if you need it done at least once then 
$docama = get_codes( $t_slot_time );

//Store current coursecode to assisgn into currentass
$currentass = $e_course_code;

//Check for common student between the last assigned course and current course to be assigned, if yes increment timeslot by 2
$chkcomms = mysql_query("SELECT student.matric, student.std_name FROM student
    JOIN course_reg e1 ON e1.matric=student.matric
    JOIN course c1 ON c1.course_code=e1.course_code
    JOIN course_reg e2 ON e2.matric=student.matric
    JOIN course c2 on c2.course_code = e2.course_code
    WHERE c1.course_code = '".$currentass."'
    AND c2.course_code RLIKE '%$docama%'
    GROUP BY student.matric") or die(mysql_error());

// Count number of rows
$num_rowe = mysql_num_rows($chkcomms);
if($num_rowe >= 1) {
    for( $i=0; $i<=$num_rowe; $i++){
        $t_slot_time = $t_slot_time + 2;
        $docama = get_codes( $t_slot_time );
        //add code to do what ever you want with $docama!
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. but what happens in between the loop?? and how do i get my new time out of the loop to use

Comment: inside the loop you put what ever code you want repeated. If you only want it repeated if it matches a condition, then use an if statement to check if it is met. If need to execute the code at the top of your source more than once then put it inside the for loop. You would need to decide which parts!

Comment: Thanks user, i do understand you but a sample with my codes above might help alot more. @user3633383

Comment: Thanks user but am not getting the new value for $t_slot_time after incrementing by 2 till condition is satisfied @user3633383